# ContextConfiguration in Spring MVC Application Test

Tags: spring, junit

When running my test class as JUnit Test, console says:

```
INFO: Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.package.mvc.AccountControllerTestDoc]
```

But my class (com.package.mvc.AccountControllerTestDoc) looks like:

```
...

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:business-config.xml")
public class AccountControllerTestDoc {
...
}
```

Why is it not found? Spring 4.2.2 is used here.

Comment: where is your business-config.xml located ? Can you screanshot your application structure tree ?

Comment: The business-config.xml is located under src/main/resources/spring/business-config.xml where src/main/resources is added to the classpath.

Comment: Ensure that test class and impl class is in the same package. This was the issue for me when having `@WebMvcTest` on test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like it doesn't work in eclipse to run the test class "as JUnit test". When running with maven it runs the tests and does find the configuration xml and it works.

Strange behaviour from eclipse since it worked previous to this change(adding a configuration xml to the test class).

Answer (score 0):

Mine looks like this :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyLoggingdemoApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class MyLoggingdemoApplicationTests {
```

Comment: I have no main application class, so I don't know which class to set for SpringApplicationConfiguration.

Answer (score 0):

Update the annotation to

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:business-config.xml"})
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still "Neither ContextConfiguration nor ContextHierarchy found for test class".